# php-fpm returning "page not found" on all requests ... permissions already checked

Tags: nginx, php

So I will start out and say that I am pretty new to web servers and this is my first that I have configured.  That being said the webserver is up and running and I can add sites and files to it just fine.  However I cannot get any .php files working right now.

I am currently running nginx on FreeBSD and have installed php-fpm.  I know that nginx is correctly using php-fpm but for any php file I try and view all I get is "file not found".  I know that this is coming from php-fpm  because for any file that actually isn't there nginx gives me a different "file not found" page.

I have looked through several google pages about this problem and the most common solution is that it is incorrect permissions on the php file.  At this point I can't rule too much out but I have tried changing the permissions for the file and folder including just opening them up to everything with no success.

Here is my nginx.conf file in the hopes that it helps.

```
user  www www;
worker_processes  4;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include         mime.types;
    index           index.html index.htm index.php
    default_type    application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log     logs/access.log main;  ## Default: off
    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      on;

    ###custom changes
    server_tokens           off;
    client_max_body_size    200M;
    client_body_buffer_size 1M;
    port_in_redirect        off;
    ###

    keepalive_timeout  15;  ## Default: 0

    gzip  on;
    ### More custom changes
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";
    ###


    server { # simple reverse-proxy
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        #access_log   logs/mySite1.access.log;

        root /usr/local/www/mySite.com;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        # this prevents hidden files (beginning with a period) from being served
        location ~ /\.          { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;      
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/local/www/nginx-dist;
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has any ideas about what is going on here they would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you out. I use the sockets of FPM, so just change to use the IP like you are but here are my working configurations:

example.com.conf

```
server {
    listen      192.168.1.1:80;
    server_name example.com;

    charset utf-8;

    access_log /vhosts/example.com/logs/access_log main;
    error_log  /vhosts/example.com/logs/error_log;

    index index.php;

    root  /vhosts/example.com/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm/nginx.sock;
        include       fastcgi.conf;
    }

    location ~ \.htaccess {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

fastcgi.conf

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you actually have a directory `/scripts` on your filesystem. You probably mean `$document_root/scripts`. If you do have a directory `/scripts` then post the php-fpm log with the SCRIPT_FILENAME logged. I think it's logged by default, but if not the syntax is explained very well in the config file.